# Point laying near line

Tags: math, geometry, line, point

I have 3 points and their coordinates. There is a line between two of them I want to find if third point is between those who create line and is near the line. On fig.1 is shown case where I can use formula to find if points are collinear. In fig.2 there is line between A and B. I want to check for point in range let`s say 15px and to find that point C is between A and B and is near to the line and ignore point D because it is far from the line.

[image: collinear]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform orthogonal projection of point `C` onto line `AB` and find the projection point `P`: the nearest to `C` point of line `AB`. Now, all you need to do is use the length of segment `CP` to determine how close `C` is to the line. And use the position of `P` with relation to `A` and `B` to determine whether `C` is "between" `A` and `B`.

Orthogonal projection of a point onto a line is a standard primitive operation in computational geometry. See [Wolfram World](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html), for one example.

I'd do it this way:

1. The normal vector of line `AB` is `(By - Ay, -(Bx - Ax))`
2. Add this vector to point `C` and obtain point `C'`

   ```
   C'x = Cx + By - Ay
   C'y = Cy - Bx + Ax
   ```
3. Find the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection) of line `AB` and line `CC'`. The intersection point is your projection point `P`.

Answer (score 4):

The distance of point **C** from line segment **AB** is the [length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_length#Euclidean_norm) of the [cross_product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Coordinate_notation) of `vector(A,C)` with `unit_vector(A,B)`.

That is to say (in pseudocode),

```
def vec_length(x,y) = sqrt(x*x + y*y)

def unitvec(ax,ay,bx,by) = (dx/m, dy/m) 
        where dx = bx - ax
              dy = by - ay
              m  = vec_length(dx,dy)

def dist_segm(cx,cy,ax,ay,ux,uy) = abs( dx*uy - dy*ux )
        where dx = cx - ax
              dy = cy - ay
```

To find out whether **C** is "between" **A** and **B** you can calculate [`dot_product`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)`( vector(A,C), unit_vector(A,B) )` and see if it's smaller than `vector_length(A,B)` (yet positive). You calculate `vector_length(A,B)` anyway as part of calculating `unit_vector(A,B)`.

This way is the most computationally efficient.